# Latest version of ember-cli compatible with ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am following the ember 2.0 guides at : http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/getting-started/

I noticed it installs ember 1.13.0 even tough I am in the 2.0 section. What is going on? Should I copy new 2.0 version in the generated ember-cli folders?

How do you setup ember-cli with ember 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the version in the `bower.config` and run `bower install` from you ember-cli folder.

Comment: I have tons of bower.json files with version to change, but I can't find bower.config. Do I really have to change 25 bower.json files with good version?

Comment: You only need to change it in the root of your ember-cli app.